# Not able to compile code. Says cant resolve symbol .. which is a method

Tags: java, android

### My mainactivity class is

```
package com.example.pirate.learning_udemy;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
Pangram newPangram = new Pangram("Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.");
newPangram.hasLetter()
}
```

---

### and my Pangram class is

```
package com.example.pirate.learning_udemy;

/**
 * Created by pirate on 15-07-2017.
 */

public class Pangram {

String stringToBeChecked;

public Pangram(String astring) {
    stringToBeChecked = astring;
}

char[] alphabets = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

char[] stringArray = stringToBeChecked.toCharArray();

public boolean hasLetter() {
    boolean doesLetterExist = true;
    for (int i =0; i < 26; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j< stringToBeChecked.length(); j++) {
            if (alphabets[i] == stringArray[j]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 0) {
            doesLetterExist = false;
        }
    }
    return doesLetterExist;
}
}
```

---

Comment: "new" word used for create new object not for method. First learn java language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The Pangram class instantiations need to be inside the onCreate method.

Comment: I suppose you have a missing } somewhere

Answer (score 1):

The code to create the new instance of the Pangram class was outside of the onCreate method, so move up into brackets of the method. You can have a try below:

```
package com.example.pirate.learning_udemy;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //below 2 line put it in method block
    Pangram newPangram = new Pangram("Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.");
    newPangram.hasLetter()

  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your method in side the on **onCreate(**) of your activity like this

So intiate Pangram class inside the onCreate method.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Pangram newPangram = new Pangram("Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.");
    newPangram.hasLetter()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a public static method. Then you don't need to create an instance of your class but can call it as

```
YourClass.hasLetters(yourString)
```